# How to match 4 character code to actual words using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

Having codes in the following format `[Alphanumeric][Letter][Alphanumeric][Alphanumeric]` i.e `A1AA`

Now I also have a dictionary of all the 4 letter words I am trying to block i.e `R2D2`

What I am looking for is a regular expression to find the matches for each code and item in my dictionary but also 1 step further and to replace characters and letters which look alike i.e. `i` and `1`, `s` and `5` and see if any matches happen there.

Anything like that out there

Comment: In your original code format specification: Alphanumeric means A-Z *and* 0-9. Do you mean alphabetic or alphanumeric? Also, letter typically means A-Z. Do you mean letter, or do you mean number or digit?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. You can use your code as a regexp and if you want to check similar characters just replace `1` with [1il]` so i.e `A1AA` will be transformed to [`A[1il]AA`](http://www.regexper.com/#A[1il]AA) and it you have `AiAA` in your dictionary it will be matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your dictionnary contains this codes:

```
R2D2
C3P0
X5ZZ
```

I would load the dictionnary and build on the fly a regex. The final regex would be:

```
(?-i)(R2D2|C3P0|X5ZZ)
```

Then apply this regex to each of your codes

```
If Regex.Matches(finalRegex) Then
   // Evil code catched
Else
   // Nice code found ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a headstart

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(@"A1AA", @"([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9])");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This part of the Regex code `[a-zA-Z0-9]` will capture any character which is alphanumeric.

You can then do a foreach loop on the matches against a dictionary of words.